# Sitefinity CMS - Overnight jobs

Tags: sitefinity

**Hi,**

We are using sitefinity 7.3 (Latest one). As per one of the requirement we would like to create some overnight jobs to perform some following:

1. Send some alerts (For certain roles).
2. Unlock all the locked pages

We have the code to perform above actions.

Now issue is that we want to do it sometime in night e.g. 3am. How we should schedule this inside sitefinity box?

Some service? If yes then any steps to achieve this?

Note: Please let me know in-case any more clarification needed.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a scheduled task to run every 5 minutes.

https://github.com/jonathanread/Aptera.Azure.LoadBalancing

```
SchedulingManager schedulingManager = SchedulingManager.GetManager();

      var newTask = new LoadBalanceTask()
      {
         Key = this.Key,
         ExecuteTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5)
      };
      schedulingManager.AddTask(newTask);
      schedulingManager.SaveChanges();
```

The Scheduling manager is what you will want to use to create the scheduled events. Here is the sitefinity documentation:
http://docs.sitefinity.com/tutorial-schedule-a-task-to-import-pop3-content

Comment: Tx Jon. I did not tried this but seems very promising. I will give it a go soon

Comment: How we should change it to execute at certain time (e.g. 2am Mon-Fri?)

Comment: And also is there way make it run only on one server in Load Balancer environment?

Comment: So set the first run to 2am the next day, when it gets rescheduled check if its friday and schedule it for the next monday. If you know the server names you could add a check for the specific server name to run only on it.

Comment: I think your code can run every 5 minutes, but is the task must run day by day at 3am, how can implement?

Comment: Instead of minutes being added you would add a day to the datetime object just set the time for that object to 3 am make sure you're using Utc time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the task only once in a load balanced environment you can also check whether the task is already running before executing it. When one webserver starts the task and changes the state of the task to 'running' some extra logic (IF state == 'running' THEN do nothing) can prevent the same task to be started again. In this way every server can start the job, so this will also work when the assigned server is accidentally offline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below.

```
var schedulingManager = SchedulingManager.GetManager();

        schedulingManager.Provider.SuppressSecurityChecks = true;

        var currentTask = schedulingManager.GetTaskData().Where(i => i.Key == sampleKey);

        foreach (var task in currentTask)
        {
            schedulingManager.DeleteTaskData(task);
        }

        var newTask = new LoadBalanceTask
        {
            Key = sampleKey,
            ExecuteTime = timeRun,
            IsRecurring = true
        };

        schedulingManager.AddTask(newTask);
        schedulingManager.SaveChanges();
```

Noted: Sitefinity Schedule will use the "UTC" format.

Comment: Need delete another task before create new the new task.